# How to use the CoreService PowerShell module using username + password

Tags: core-service, powershell

Using [my favourite PowerShell](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules) module I was wondering how to access the Core Service using username and password instead of using the current user's Windows credentials.

The commands in the PowerShell module use the `Get-TridionCoreServiceClient` commandlet. This uses the current logged on user's credentials to connect to the Core Service. Optionally you can impersonate another user.

Now I am connecting from my local machine to the CMS server, using different credentials so I would like to pass or set my username and password to `Get-TridionCoreServiceClient` and other commands.

Comment: This is one of the open issues for the PowerShell modules (https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/issues/4). I'll get around to it eventually! If you get something working, please do share or make a pull request :)

Comment: I will definately do a PR when I get something working.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution to get a `CoreServiceClient` using a plain username and password.

```
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = $credentials
$client.GetCurrentUser()
```

This will get a Core Service client object, using the settings set by `Set-CoreServiceSettings`. Then actually before using the client to call the server the credentials are added.

This however does not work for the other PowerShell module commands. If you would try to use `Get-TridionUser` instead of `$client.GetCurrentUser()` it will fail. The `Get-TridionUser` command will construct a new client without your credentials.

Comment: hmm, `Set-CoreServiceSettings` has a `-Username` parameter. I think this username is not used in any of the `Tridion-CoreService` commandlets.